# SOAP connection problems after 1.9.3.0 update

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, magento1.9.2.4, ce-1.9.3.0

I have updated my Magento Store from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.0

We use shipping software (Shipworks) that connects via a SOAP/XML-RPC user.

After the update shipworks logging shows this response in the logs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
-<SOAP-ENV:Body>
-<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>1</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error. Please see log for details.</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So I went and turned on exception logging in Magento and get the following error:

```
2016-10-13T18:24:14+00:00 ERR (3): 
SoapFault exception: [1] Internal Error. Please see log for details. in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php:196
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(140): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap->fault('1', 'Internal Error....')
#1 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(48): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->_fault('internal')
#2 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(559): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->handlePhpError(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/home/deepsix/p...', 559, Array)
#3 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(299): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->processingMethodResult('<?xml version="...')
#4 [internal function]: Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->call('ca4d34d100c92c8...', 'shipWorksApi.ge...', Array)
#5 /public_html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php(889): SoapServer->handle('<?xml version="...')
#6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php(174): Zend_Soap_Server->handle()
#7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php(138): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap->run()
#8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/controllers/SoapController.php(40): Mage_Api_Model_Server->run()
#9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Api_SoapController->indexAction()
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

So I have went and done a diff between the Abstract.php from 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.0 and get the following:

```
290a291
>                 $result = array();
292c293
<                     return $model->$method((is_array($args) ? $args : array($args)));
---
>                     $result = $model->$method((is_array($args) ? $args : array($args)));
294c295
<                     return $model->$method($args);
---
>                     $result = $model->$method($args);
296c297
<                     return call_user_func_array(array(&$model, $method), $args);
---
>                     $result = call_user_func_array(array(&$model, $method), $args);
297a299
>                 return $this->processingMethodResult($result);
403a406
>                     $callResult = array();
405c408
<                         $result[] = $model->$method((is_array($args) ? $args : array($args)));
---
>                         $callResult = $model->$method((is_array($args) ? $args : array($args)));
407c410
<                         $result[] = $model->$method($args);
---
>                         $callResult = $model->$method($args);
409c412
<                         $result[] = call_user_func_array(array(&$model, $method), $args);
---
>                         $callResult = call_user_func_array(array(&$model, $method), $args);
410a414
>                     $result[] = $this->processingMethodResult($callResult);
544a549,585
>     }
> 
>     /**
>      * Prepare Api data for XML exporting
>      * See allowed characters in XML:
>      * @link http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Char
>      *
>      * @param array $result
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function processingMethodResult(array $result)
>     {
>         foreach ($result as &$row) {
>             if (!is_null($row) && !is_bool($row) && !is_numeric($row)) {
>                 $row = $this->processingRow($row);
>             }
>         }
>         return $result;
>     }
> 
>     /**
>      * Prepare Api row data for XML exporting
>      * Convert not allowed symbol to numeric character reference
>      *
>      * @param $row
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function processingRow($row)
>     {
>         $row = preg_replace_callback(
>             '/[^\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]/u',
>             function ($matches) {
>                 return '&#' . Mage::helper('core/string')->uniOrd($matches[0]) . ';';
>             },
>             $row
>         );
>         return $row;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same error with another extension here. system.log says

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::processingMethodResult() must
>   be of the type array, string given, called in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php...

I think the problem is the new method

`Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::processingMethodResult(array $result)`

which only accepts arrays. So every Api function returning a scalar value will throw this error. To get this going again i copied `app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php` and patched `processingMethodResult`:

```
public function processingMethodResult($result)
{
    if (is_array($result)) {
        foreach ($result as &$row) {
            if (!is_null($row) && !is_bool($row) && !is_numeric($row)) {
                if (is_array($row)) {
                    $row = $this->processingMethodResult($row);
                } else {
                    $row = $this->processingRow($row);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!is_null($result) && !is_bool($result) && !is_numeric($result)) {
            $result = $this->processingRow($result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: which version of magento are you running?

Comment: This does fix the problem.  Why would the magento core file be changed to array vs string anyway here?

Comment: Excellent fix, thank you. Has anyone raised this as a bug with Magento? Lots of people are going to get bitten by this.

Comment: The change is more around PHP7, see my answer below. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4103536/158325 it's not really a bug, but makes the API PHP7 compatible.

Comment: @LandonL: I updated from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.0.

Comment: @B00MER makes the API PHP7 compatible (was it really not compatible before?) but breaks the compatibility with PHP < 7? I would say that is a bug. We use the latest 5.6.x release and the 1.9.3.0 update has broken the API on every store that I've seen.

Comment: This fix seems to have moved the problem to `Array to string conversion` in `/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php` for me.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the Magento bug regarding this so we can track when they have resolved it or if they even plan to? I can't seem to get the Magento bug tracker to load for me.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the ShipStation module and/or the PHP version you are running isn't compatible:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s

Guessing off the truncated PHP error message that's returned:

`Argument 1 pass...'` is most likely `Argument 1 passed to methodhere() must be an instance of string, string given`

What version of PHP are you running and have you consulted with ShipStation to see if they have any newer version and/or compatibility issues with the latest Magento version/patches.

Also, you can add a bit more logging here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php#L889 to capture more of the truncated PHP error that's being returned, to get validation that it is the correct error being returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I get more of the truncated error? I am uncertain how to increase the length of the line.

Comment: The system is currently running php 5.6.25, I called shipworks today, but since the magento update 1.9.3.0 just came out yesterday, I don't believe they have had a chance to look at the issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

Belgors answer really helped me, but I ended up modifying the patch slightly to allow for extra objects to be included in the API reposnse.

For example you now get ***aheadWorks storecredit and/or giftcard*** object-arrays with the Magento XML-RPC call for order information.

(code updated from suggestion by Björn Tantau - to better work with objects & collections)

```
public function processingMethodResult($result)
{
    if (is_object($result) && is_callable(array($result, 'toArray'))) {
        $result = $result->toArray();
    }
    if (is_array($result)) {
        foreach ($result as &$row) {
            if (is_object($row) && is_callable(array($row, 'toArray'))) {
                $row = $row->toArray();
            }
            if (!is_null($row) && !is_bool($row) && !is_numeric($row)) {
                if (is_array($row)) {
                    $row = $this->processingMethodResult($row);
                } else {
                    $row = $this->processingRow($row);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!is_null($result) && !is_bool($result) && !is_numeric($result)) {
            $result = $this->processingRow($result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```